# iOS Views and UI/UX

Tags: ios, uitableview, user-interface, view

I'm new to iOS and have been looking at views. How are apps like lets say instagram and wells fargo laying out there apps? Do people use table views mostly? Is there like an HTML view?

Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/Introduction/Introduction.html. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a HTML View (UIWebView). But the UX is not as good as a "native" App. For example used this view. And the performance was pretty poor. I have no idea how instagram do it, but with a Table View your are extremely flexible because you can put every view inside a Table View Row.

Comment: oh cool, i didn't know you can nest the views inside a tableview row. Thx, I'm still reading and learning.